# What is wrong with my code? (Trying to create a slider)

Tags: html, css, image, slider, slideshow

```
// Html

<div class="hero">
  <ul>
    <li><img src="images/wallpaper.jpg"/></li>
    <li><img src="images/wallpaperTwo.jpg"/></li>
    <li><img src="images/wallpaperThree.jpg"/></li>
    <li><img src="images/wallpaperFour.jpg"/></li>
  </ul>
</div>

// Css

.hero {
  position: relative;
  top:0;
  left:0;
 }

.hero ul {
 width:400%;
 display:block;
}

.hero ul li {
 float:left;
 }

 .hero ul li img {
  width:100%;
  display:block;
  height:94vh;
  }
```

The following picture show that the first image cuts off towards the end. How do I fix that problem? This is really frustrating so any help is greatly appreciated!

[Click here for Image!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/whhCV.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your example code is that the `li` doesn't have a width. Normally, with block type elements, the width will be the width of the parent, but with floating elements, that won't work.

Solution: give the `li` a width of 25%.

Also, I suspect you may want to remove the margins everywhere, so I set those to 0 too.

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
}
.hero ul {
  margin: 0; padding: 0;
  width: 400%;
}
.hero ul li {
  float: left;
  margin: 0; padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  width: 25%;
}
.hero ul li img {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  height: 94vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="hero">
  <ul>
    <li><img src="http://lorempixel.com/500/500" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://lorempixel.com/g/500/500" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://lorempixel.com/500/500" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://lorempixel.com/g/500/500" /></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Comment: Did it work? In that case, can you click the check mark to the left, to mark the problem as solved, so that your question no longer shows up in the list of unsolved ones.